# onBackPressed and onKeyDown not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

I have one activity in my app and I have 2 fragments - *A* and *B*. In *MainActivity* layout there is a FrameLayout. From *MainActivity* I call FragmentManager to load fragment A into FrameLayout. Then, from *fragment A* I load *fragment B* into FrameLayout.
In my *fragment B* I implement *onBackPressed()* and *onKeyDown(int _a, KeyEvent _b)* from *MainActivity* to make back button work with *WebView* in fragment B. 
But it works as if I didn't implement it!

MainActivity interface:

```
public interface onKeyDownListener {
    public void onBackPressed();

    public boolean onKeyDown(int _a, KeyEvent _b);
}
```

Fragment B implementation:

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return getActivity().onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mWebView.isFocused() && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "This's working!", 50000).show();
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

No one of these methods works, back button just close the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onBackPressed is a function on the activity, not the fragment.  You'll have to catch it in the Activity and pass it on to the fragment to process

Comment: What do you mean? I tried to @Override it but it didn't work too.

Comment: Fragments don't have an onBackPressed function.  So that's why it isn't being called.  Activities have them, not Fragments.  @Override not working should have told you that Fragments don't have a function named that, so it wouldn't be called.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I implement these functions from MainActivity. Should I do it in a different way?

Comment: That's not what you say above-  you say above that they're part of your fragment.  You look like you have things backwards-  you have the fragment expecting to get the back key and calling Activity, it needs to be Activity getting the back key and calling Fragment.